# Child-modal is empty on every second click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

I am using row-selected on Bootstrap table, so that when a user select a row in a table, the data of that table is passed to a new object which is then sent as a prop to a child component, which is a modal.

The issue is that when I first click on a row, the modal opens and shows the data correctly, but if I close the modal and click the same row again, the data object is empty and nothing gets shown. I need to click it again for a third time to see the data. Then if I click a fourth time, the data is gone again.

I don't understand it, because in my showModal method, I check first to see if selectedRows are empty or not, so it shouldn't open if there was no data.

Any idea why this happens?

Parent:

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-card class="mt-4 mb-4">
      <h5>{{ $t('errorLogs.errorLog') }}</h5>
      <b-table
        :items="completedTasks"
        :fields="fields"
        :per-page="[10, 25, 50]"
        selectable
        :select-mode="'single'"
        @row-selected="onRowSelected"
        @row-clicked="showModal"
        include-actions
        sort-desc
      />
    </b-card>
    <error-log-entry-modal ref="errorLogEntryModal" :selected-error-log="selectedRows"/>


  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
  import ErrorLogEntryModal from '@/components/error-log/ErrorLogEntryModal';
  export default {
    components: {
      ErrorLogEntryModal,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        errors: null,
        tasksCompleted: null,
        selectedRows: []


      };
    },
    computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'done',
            label: '',
            thStyle: 'width: 1%',
            template: {
              type: 'checkbox',
              includeCheckAllCheckbox: true,
            },
          },
          {
            key: 'priority',
            label: this.$t('errorLogs.priority'),
            formatter: type => this.$t(`model.errors.types.${type}`),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'creationDateTime',
            label: this.$t('creationDateTime'),
            formatter: date => moment(date).locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'stackTraceShort',
            label: this.$t('errorLogs.stackTrace'),
            sortable: true,
          },
          {
            key: 'message',
            label: this.$t('message'),
            sortable: true
          },
        ]
      },
    
      completedTasks(){
        if(this.errors){
          return this.errors.filter(log => log.done)
        }
      },
    },
    methods: {
      load(){
          errorService.getErrorLogs().then(result => {
            result.data.forEach(log => log.stackTraceShort = log.stackTrace.substring(0,30));
            this.errors = result.data

          })
      },
      submit(){
        this.$bvModalExt
          .msgBoxYesNo(
            this.$t('archiveErrorLog'),
            {
              title: this.$t('pleaseConfirm'),
              okVariant: 'success'
            }
          ).then(value => {
            if (value) {
              errorService.updateStatusOnErrorEntryLog(this.errors)
            }
        })
      },
      onRowSelected(fields){
        this.selectedRows = fields
      },
 
      showModal(){
        if (this.selectedRows) {
          this.$refs.errorLogEntryModal.show()
        }
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.load()
    },

  };
</script>
```

child:

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    modal-class="error-log-modal"
    v-model="showModal"
    ok-only
    size="xl">
    <b-row class="lg-12" v-for="log in selectedErrorLog">
      <b-col class="ml-2 mr-2 mb-4">
        <h4>{{ $t('errorLogs.errorMessage') }}</h4>
        {{ log.message }}
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row class="lg-12">
      <b-col class="ml-2 mr-2"><h4>{{ $t('errorLogs.stackTrace') }}</h4></b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row class="lg-12" v-for="log in selectedErrorLog">
      <b-col class="ml-2 mr-2" style="word-break: break-word; background-color: #F5C9C1;">
        {{ log.stackTrace }}
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    props: {
      selectedErrorLog: Array
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showModal: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      show(){
        this.showModal = true
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: When you click on the row to open the modal, does that also trigger an (un-)select event?

Comment: No, it only triggers the showModal event.